# How to fix Variable ' ' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it

Tags: swift, xcode

I am getting

```
Variable 'rollerSmall' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it
```

error. how do I fix it? It's a warning. I'm trying to do this:

```
    if roller == "1"{
        var rollerSmall: Bool = true
    }
    if roller == "2"{
        var rollerSmall: Bool = false
        var rollerMedium: Bool = true
    }
        
    }
```

Comment: its not an error. Its just a simple awareness by Xcode, because you are not accessing value of rollerSmall no where else in loop. So to save memory allocation its making you aware.

Comment: You are not using `rollerSmall` anywhere, thus the warning. What do you actually want to achieve with that code?

Comment: You are only setting a value to 'rollerMedium,' which has not been practically used like if rollerSmall {}.

Answer (score 0):

Variables have *scope*; it matters *where* you declare a variable. The problem is that you are declaring your variable *inside* the if clauses. But you will probably want to declare it, and use it, *outside* the if clauses. For example:

```
var rollerSmall = false
var rollerMedium = false
if roller == "1" {
    rollerSmall = true
}
if roller == "2" {
    rollerMedium = true
}
// use rollerSmall and rollerMedium here
```

Having said all that, this is probably still a terrible way of doing whatever you are trying to do. You should not be encoding things in this flimsy way. If your roller can only have states small and medium, for example, that is an *enum* and you shouldn't have integer values and different variables at all.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: I think I've answered the question you asked.